# AFrame - sampler3D in fragment shader

Tags: three.js, webgl, aframe, fragment-shader

Is it webgl2 supported by aframe? I am trying to use

```
precision mediump sampler3D
```

in a fragment shader and I got this error:

```
THREE.WebGLShader: gl.getShaderInfoLog() fragment ERROR: 0:106: 'sampler3D' : Illegal use of reserved word
ERROR: 0:106: 'sampler3D' : syntax error
```

I read by default threejs supports webgl1 and I haveto add a script tag in the html in order to support webgl2.

```
<script src="/path/to/WebGL.js"></script>
```

Also, I tried adding the shader version at the beginning of the file, but then it says:

```
'version' : #version directive must occur before anything else, except for comments and white space
```

Is there a way to do this in aframe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I made it work (at least it's a milestone).

The problem is the webgl context Aframe initializes the scene with. By default it is webgl, not webgl2. The reserved word "sampler3D" is only available in webgl2, and that is the reason I was getting the error.
I had to clone the aframe repository, in the file src\core\scene\a-scene.js modify the method setupCanvas and add the support for webgl2:

```
canvasEl = document.createElement('canvas');
var contextEl = canvasEl.getContext( 'webgl2' );
sceneEl.context = contextEl;
```

and in the method setupRenderer() add the property:

```
context: this.context,
```

to the rendererConfig map.

That made run my "precision mediump sampler3D" line on my shaders.